# CSS: How to create two column semi-liquid layout?

Tags: css

I want to create a two column layout where width of left column depends on screen width as follows:

- when `0 <= screen width <= c` left column width is `a`
- when `c <= screen width <= d` left column width changes linearly from `[a,b]`
- when `d <= screen width` left column width = `b`

and right column takes up whatever space is left. How can I do this with just css? This layout will be used in a map app, where left column displays search results, and right column displays the map.

Comment: @Lowkase, I whish I would have a gold badge for questions like this, don't you? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The whole `x <= screen width <= y` thing sounds like `@media (max-width: 1234px)` or something similar to me. So I would suggest you use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the OP, but may have a solution for the case when a=b=c=d. Will update if I find a better solution.

HTML:

```
<div id="main">         
    <div id="serp"></div>                
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main
{
    width:100%;
}

#serp
{
    float:left;
    width:210px;        
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid black; 
}

#mapDiv
{
    margin-left:220px;
    position:relative;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

The `position:relative` is needed because when the map control is added as a child element of `#mapDiv` it has an inline style with `position:absolute;left=0px;top=0px;right=0px`

complete example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-eqiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <style type="text/css"> 
        #main
{
    width:100%;
}

#serp
{
    float:left;
    width:210px;        
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid black; 
}

#mapDiv
{
    margin-left:220px;
    position:relative;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="serp"></div>
        <div id="mapDiv"></div>
    </div>
    <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0">
    </script>   
    <script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript">
        document.body.onload = (function()
        {
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {credentials:"Your Bing Maps Key"});
        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```